# No Dom0 in "virsh list"

Tags: xen

Basically I am trying to setup a cloud with Ubuntu 12.04, Eucalyptus and Xen.

I have installed Xen. Now when I run `xm list` command, it shows Domain-0 is running. But when I try with `virsh list`, nothing is populated. Even `virsh list --all` does not produce any output.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think with virsh you need to explicitly tell it where to connect to as well, so the correct command, given that the qemu instance you want to connect to is local, would be

```
virsh -c qemu:///system list --all
```

or with xen, I guess it might be (unsure here)

```
virsh -c xen:/// list --all
```

It's likely possible to configure virsh to use this a the default location, I don't know if there's a reason the virsh package does not do that automatically.

Comment: Still not working

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue using the latest Ubuntu 14.04 with Libvirt 1.2.2.

If I run

```
virsh version
```

I will have this

> Compiled against library: libvirt 1.2.2
>   Using library: libvirt 1.2.2
>   Using API: QEMU 1.2.2
>   Running hypervisor: QEMU 1.7.91

I guess the problem is that libvirt connect to QEMU instead of xen. I modified /etc/libvirt/libvirt.conf and added this line
uri_default = "xen:///"

Save and run this

```
virsh version
```

I will have this

> Compiled against library: libvirt 1.2.2 
>   Using library: libvirt 1.2.2
>   Using API: Xen 1.2.2 
>   Running hypervisor: Xen 4.4.0

However, I still didn't see dom0 in virsh list --all. :-( 
It doesn't seem to affect virt-manager to create vm. So it is not that bad.